# In nestjs bcrypt always return true with jwt token

Tags: nestjs, prisma, bcrypt

In our rest api when someone logs in his jwt refresh token is stored in a database after after encrypting with bcrypt and when the user want to get a new access token the api will check if the refresh token is still in the database by comparing the jwt from the header and from the database, but it always return true

Nestjs + prisma + postgres

```js
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
export function encryptData(data: string) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(data, bcrypt.genSaltSync());
}
export function compareData(data: string, hashed: string) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(data, hashed);
}
```

This is there the refresh token is pushed to the database

```js
refreshTokens: Array<string>
```

```js
async pushNewRefreshToken(refreshToken: string, userId: number) {
    return this.prismaService.users.update({
        data: {
            refreshTokens: {
                push: encryptData(refreshToken),
            },
        },
        where: { userId },
    });
}
```

And the is where we compare

```js
async checkRefreshToken(refreshToken: string, userId: number) {
    const user = await this.getUserService.getUserById(userId);
    if (user.refreshTokens) {
        for (const token of user.refreshTokens) {
            if (compareData(refreshToken, token)) {
                Logger.log('Token match')
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I  tried to log out everything and I didn't get it why this not working

Answer (score 0):

Bcrypt's methods are asynchronous, they return `Promise`s. A `Promise` is `truthy` regardless of its outcome when just doing a `!!promise` check. You need to `await` the result of the promise to know whether it is the same token or not

Comment: `hashSync` and `compareSync` is not async so this was not the problem

Comment: Ah, apologies, I missed that in the implementation and only saw the `compareData` call, not the function itself. The only thing I can think is that in pulling back the refresh tokens there's _something_ that's matching what the user is sending. I'd verify what data you are getting back in `user.refreshTokens` and save the `compareData` call to a variable so you can log out `token ${refreshToken} ${isSame ? 'did' : 'did not'} match to hash {token} after hashing`